# How dynamically in the parameterized constructor?

Tags: c++

i wnat this object"name_of_pro"is allocated dynamically in the 
parameterized constructor.
i am trying but i think  is not true

---------------------------------------...

```
class employee{ 
string name, ID, *name_of_pro; 
int age ; 
float salary ; 
public: 
employee(){}; 

employee ( string n,int ag, float sa , string name_pro){ // constructor. parameterized 
name=n; 
age=ag; 
salary=sa; 
name_of_pro=new string; 
}
```

i hope help plz.

Comment: Your code currently *does* dynamically allocate an object of type `string` and lets `name_of_pro` point to it. I'm not sure *why* anyone would want to do that, though. A `string`, if it is a `std::string`, already uses dynamic memory allocation internally.

Comment: my question university want this (':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your question, but I think what you might mean is that you want to have `name_of_pro` be a copy of `name_pro`.

```
employee ( string n, int ag, float sa , string name_pro){ 
    name=n; 
    age=ag; 
    salary=sa; 
    name_of_pro=new string(name_pro);  // You can make a pointer to a copy this way
}
```

You just need to make sure you delete the string `name_of_pro` in the destructor if this is what you want to do.

```
~employee() {
    delete name_of_pro;
}
```

What may be even easier is an initialization list instead of all of the simple assignments.

```
employee ( string name, int age, float salary , string name_pro) : 
        name(name), age(age), salary(salary), name_of_pro(new string(name_pro)) { 
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I'll add that just to show you can do it, but I think dynamic allocation in the initialization list in a lot of cases isn't a good idea.